# How do I make a menu in HTML which appears as a tab until clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website and would like to create a page with a menu which appears as a tab until  a user clicks on it. This should expand the menu to display its contents. Once the tab is clicked again, I want it to disappear. How can I do this (preferably using jQuery)?

Comment: use handler of click event of your tab element, simple like that

Comment: By searching Google. This is probably the 3rd most common JavaScript behavior on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    .menu > li > ul {display:none;}
    .menu > li.active > ul {display:block;}
</style>

<ul class="menu">
        <li>
            Menu item 1
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu 1.1</li>
                <li>Submenu 1.2</li>
            </ul>  
        </li>   
        <li>
            Menu item 2
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu 2.1</li>
                <li>Submenu 2.2</li>
            </ul>     
        </li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.menu > li').on("click", function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```